# Macbook Pro 16" overheating external display and no scaling option

Tags: macbook-pro, display, activity-monitor

This is just with the monitor connected running in mirror mode, just one safer tab opened.

[image]

This with the closed lid in clamshell mode running colder, but so tiny image at 2k resolution (or blurry at full hd) because of the scaled option missing!
[image]

which is instead present in the built in display
[image]

Comment: A 27" 2560x1440 display will not be considered a retina/HiDPI [because it isn't one] so you don't get the retina-style scaling options, I'm afraid.

Comment: I mean it is fraud apple does warn you about that or give indication at all, as a list of compatible monitors... I was never expecting this, every other laptop with ubuntu and windows had no problem.

Comment: It's fully compatible, it's just not a HiDPI screen, it's standard dot-pitch. I'm looking at two of them right now.

Comment: if fact it is impossible to use, at 2k it is too small, cannot read it, at lower resolution not sharp at all, very bad quality image. moreover i have read that only few monitors do not result in overheating which makes the mac incandescent and loud. i call it not compatible because the displayed image is unusable.

Comment: I find 2k 27" screens perfectly legible. Of course, if you set it to a lower resolution the image will degrade, because it is not a HiDPI screen, so it doesn't work the same way. Adding any external monitor will cause any GPU to run hotter, it has more work to do. If you don't like it, send it back.

Comment: on ubuntu and windows laptop you have the scaling option to make icons and text bigger and it does not run so hot such you cannot touch it and super loud funs...